# Fortify fix for Often Misused: Authentication - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, fortify

I got "Often Misused: Authentication" issue while fortify done my code scan. I am getting issue from below line of code

```
    IPHostEntry serverHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName);
```

When I Googled I found some solutions but I am unable to get it. Do I need to create a False positive for this issue or Can I rewrite the code and give a fix. This is used only for logging purpose. I am not satisfied with creating FP ticket. How can i get serverhost without using Dns.GetHostEntry.Can anybody suggest any fix for this issue.

Comment: Security concerns about DNS cache poisoning aside, this is a bad approach for getting an IP address for the local server, and you are not guaranteed to get the actual IP address the client is connecting with this way. Consider `HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, But still I am facing the Fortify issue  and the issue is mainly due to using GetHostEntry() method.